# Altium short circuit error at x=0 mm, y=0 mm. Don't know why

Tags: altium

I have found 824 short circuit errors at [x=0 mm] [y=0 mm]. I think they came from I copy/paste polygons. But I don't know to solve them.

[image]

I have checked there is nothing selectable at this original point. It's strange. Any idea on them?

[image]

Comment: The error is likely at the location of the Via.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying the via located at (10.687mm, 182mm) is colliding with the polygon with its origin located at (0mm, 0mm). Try repouring your polygons first - shortcut T-G-A. If that doesn't work, go to the (10.687mm, 182mm) coordinate and you'll find the shorting via. Make sure your clearance rules are set up appropriately.

Comment: fancy! it's my rule setting problem.

Comment: I set clearance rule for different objects on layer 3. However, vias are multi-layer objects so it's not reported even when short circuit occurs in my design!

Comment: You should probably set your electrical clearance rule to something like 6mils (0.15mm) without specifying objects - it will become the standard clearance rule for the entire board

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in the View configuration windows that every objects are "visible" ?

[image]